# how to include jquery in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-validation-engine

i am new to jquery and codeigniter but not programming i have done some validation before with javascript.
i wanna use jquery in my project and validate the form inputs plz help me step by step

**1**.how to include jquery?
   **2**.how to use it to validate the form?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form" action="<?php echo $form_action; ?>" method="post">
 <center><h1><?php echo $form_h1; ?></h1></center>
<table width="800" border="1" bordercolor="BLUE" align="center" cellpadding="5"    cellspacing="2">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>FirstName</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
   <span class="firstname_error_msg" style="color: #ff0000;"></span>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>LastName</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">

 </td>
</tr>
<tr> You can <em>not</em> use Markdown in here.
 <td>
  <b>Address</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
  <span class="address_error_msg" style="color: #ff0000;"></span>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>Email Id</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
  <span class="email_error_msg" style="color: #ff0000;"></span>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>Password</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
  <span class="password_error_msg" style="color: #ff0000;"></span>
 </td>
</tr> You can <em>not</em> use Markdown in here.
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>Gender</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="gender">
   <option value="M">Male</option>
   <option value="F">Female</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>Date Of Birth</b>
 </td>
 <td>
   <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>Age</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="age" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>Zipcode</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode"/>
  <span class="zipcode_error_msg" style="color: #ff0000;"></span>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b>Mobile</b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="mobile"/>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="100%" align="center"  >
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
  <input id="reset" type="reset"  value="Reset">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll find all you need in the CI Javascript Integeration Library documentation at: `ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/javascript.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 1**

to use jquery in your page you need too add this line in your HTML head **(in your view)**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

you can find the valid address to add; at the end of [jquery page](http://jquery.com).

**step 2**

to test jquery included Properly add this code

```
<script>
  $.(document).ready(function(){ alert("hello"); });
</script>
```

if alert shown and firebug console didn't show any error. it's included correctly.

**step 3**

you can use codeigniter validaitor or jquery validiator to validate your form data. use these refrence for every offer.

[validate with codeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

[validate with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script)

Comment: `$.(document).ready(function(){ alert("hello"); });` doesn't work for me, I had to remove the first period. `$(document).ready(function(){ alert("hello"); });`

Answer (score 0):

In head sector of your code just copy paste the code given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use google jquery url.

For local file, use below code in your template header to include in all pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js file"></script>
```

Then you can use any jquery validation plugin / tool now.

Try below URL for demo and code:

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html