# Foms: One warning for all required fields

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form with 3 required fields: name, email, and subject.
If I create a rule for each one, they open 3 warnings. I prefer just the same warning for all the fields (they all have to be fill, otherwise the form won't be submitted).

For now, I succeed to do with email. But I was wondering if I can do something like:

```
var validator = new FormValidator('contactos-form', [{
        name: 'nome,email,assunto',
        rules: 'required'
    }]
```

How can I do this?
Please, help! :) Thank you

```
<div class="formArea">

    <div class="main-content-block-entry">

        <form method="post" name="contactos-form" class="add-comment-form" action="#">

            <input type="hidden" value="rodolfovieiradias@gmail.com" name="emailReceiver">
            <p><input type="text" placeholder="nome/ empresa" name="nome" class="nome"><input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" class="email"></p>

            <p><textarea placeholder="assunto" name="assunto" class="assunto"></textarea></p>

            <p><button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="submit"></i> Submeter</button></p>

            <div class="statusMensagem"></div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
<script>                    
var validator = new FormValidator('contactos-form', [{
        name: 'email',
        rules: 'email',
        rules: 'required'

    }], function(errors, evt) {
        var SELECTOR_ERRORS = $('.statusMensagem');           


        if (errors.length > 0) {
            SELECTOR_ERRORS.empty();

            for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
                SELECTOR_ERRORS.append(errors[i].message + '<br />');
            }


            SELECTOR_ERRORS.fadeIn(200);
        } else {

            SELECTOR_ERRORS.css({ display: 'none' });

            // Tens de chamar a função que vai enviar os dados para o servidor
            enviaform();
        }

        if (evt && evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if (event) {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
    });

console.debug(validator);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this by editing definition of FormValidator method in validator javascript file.

Simple solution is u add FormValidator method like :

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });
```

Refrence: [A simple jQuery form validation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script)

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuPPy/)

Comment: Thank you Manwal for your quick answer, but I'm no get anything. What should I change/delete from may code written above?