# Alphanumeric method doesn't work with the validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

Can anyone please tell me why  this method doesn’t work here .(‘ alphanumeric:true’) 
Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true,
     alphanumeric:true, //I’m not sure about this if this is wrong  please tell me

            },
        },


        messages: {
            fname: "Please enter your first name",

        },


        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.validate.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="final.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="additional-methods.js"></script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form id="myform"> 
            <input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/> 
            <input type="text" name="field2" /> <br/> 
            <input type="submit" /> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: According to the docs - http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate alphanumeric is not an option.

Comment: @ Jay   I got this from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script  &
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js

Comment: Is that the plugin that you're using?

Comment: Have you added the additional-methods.js file to your page?

Comment: @ Jay ,,here is my html code <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="final.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="additional-methods.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>




</body>



</html>

Comment: Can you add that to your post above, it is hard to read in a comment. Have you checked your browser's console to make sure that everything has loaded properly?

Comment: @ Jay it's bit difficult to add here :(

Comment: Open up your browser's console and make sure that there are no errors.

Comment: @ Jay ..is there another option instead of using   alphanumeric:true, ..but I think this is easy isn't it ..sorry I don't know much about JQuery  I'm still learning

Comment: The other option may be much more complex. What browser are you using?

Comment: @ Jay .. google chrome

Comment: I think I need to find another option to get this answer

Comment: Click F12 while you're focused on Chrome @Erandi and the console windows will popup.

Comment: Hmm..First time I'm using it ..

Comment: :) You'll find it to be a very valuable tool.

Comment: @ Jay ..anyway Thanks a lot friend  I will try another method.I just want to validate that user has entered text and alphanumeric character seems like this method doesn't work out  :(

Comment: @ Jay yeah I'll try that in future .. :) :)  thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be your only issue, but I can tell you that this will not work in older versions of IE.

Although it is perfectly valid syntax, per JS standards, IE does not like it when you leave in trailing commas after the last element of an array.

I have noted these issue commas in your code, below:

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        fname: {
            required: true,
            alphanumeric:true, //trailing comma
        }, //trailing comma
    },


    messages: {
        fname: "Please enter your first name", //trailing comma
    },


    submitHandler: function (form) { 
        alert('valid form submitted'); 
        return false; 
    }
});
```

Comment: This is more of a comment since it does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I disagree, as I did point out a bug in his code. He did not reference a specific browser, so I started with the basics. I was about to reference your comment in my answer, however, as the more likely direct cause of the issue, but was going to give you the option to post it as an answer, first.

Comment: Go ahead and mention the other issue, because that is likely the bigger problem here. I agree about the commas, he may not be seeing that issue because he may not be testing in IE. BTW - I think IE 10 and 11 come on board and don't fuss about the commas, but I have not tested that.

Comment: @ Jay  & Zachary ... not he ..she  :P  ..I'm using chrome

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I believe that you are correct, and I meant to say "older IE." I will update my post. My apologies, Erandi.

Comment: My apologies too, @Erandi. :)

Comment: Still I couldn't solve this problem @ Zachary ..friend,your code didn't work