# Validate form fields when the form is posting

Tags: jquery, forms, ajax.beginform

I designed a form (using `Ajax.BeginForm` method) for POST and GET dual purposes. Default HTTP method is `GET`. I am

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "Home",
    null,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "updateArea",
        HttpMethod = "Get",
    }){
       /* Form fields,*/
       <input id="Add" type="button" value="Add" /> 
       <input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" /> 
    }
```

How do I [validate the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script) only when the form is posting (for instance `$.post` or `$.ajax({type:'POST'})`)?

Comment: use [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal any non-plugin solutions? Also I don't want validation when the form is GETting

Comment: Do you want this validation client-side or server-side?

Comment: @neilsimp1 Client side

Comment: @DylanChensky You might look at putting a `beforeSend` function in [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), check if it's a POST request, and if so, validate.