# How to do for loop for display all errors at once in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am currently working on JavaScript form validation. For individual it is applying all errors but my task is to loop all element at once and display error at once. Is there any solution?

```
<form action="" id="register" onsubmit="return validation()">
  Name<input type="text" id="name">
  <p id="error"></p>
  Email<input type="text" id="email">
  <p id="error"></p>
  Password<input type="text" id="password">
  <p id="error"></p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
  function validation() {
    if (document.getElementById('name').value=="") {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Please fill your name";
    }
    and so.. on..
  }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me how to for loop all errors to display at once when user click submit buttton?

Comment: `id` should be unique in same document... do you have any validation code?

Comment: @zakaria Acharki. Please check code once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,  create an *error box*. This can be done using a simply div.

```
<div id="error-box" style="color: red"></div>
```

Second, you don't need to chain infinite `if` statements. You can use the fantastic and wonderful `for` loop!

```
function validation() {
  var inputs = document.forms['myForm'].getElementsByTagName('input').length;

  for (i = 0; i <= inputs; i++) {
    if (document.forms['myForm'][i].value == "") {
        document.getElementById("error-box").innerHTML="Please fill " + document.forms['myForm'][i].name;
    }
  }
}
```

This will create an array of inputs and read one by one. If any field is empty, it will return an error into your error box. If not, execution continues.

Or you can use jQuery and Validation plugin. Check here for more info. [A simple jQuery form validation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script)

Happy coding!

Comment: Mr. Juanjo Salvador. I run your code on script. it is not looping it. Will please go through it.

Comment: Hi Your code is fine there are few things are not working fine. Will you please check it once and please do this working example in fiddle. It will help me alot. Thank you

Comment: Hi The code you written in jsfiddle.net. unable to open. Will you please check it once. I am getting 404 error. We're truly sorry, but there is no such page. Thanks Juanjo Salvador. you are helping me a lot.

Comment: jsFiddle is going wrong... Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/jsalvador/21abrxg7/

Comment: the above code is not working for my html code , please share the related html code.

Answer (score 2):

First the `id` should be unique in same document so you have to replace duplicate ones by classes, e.g :

```
 Name<input type="text" id="name">
 <p class="error"></p>

 Email<input type="text" id="email">
 <p class="error"></p>

 Password<input type="text" id="password">
 <p class="error"></p>
```

Then just show the error message of the input in the related `.error` paragraph :

```
function validation() {
   if ($('#name').val()==="") {
       $('#name').next(".error").html("Please fill your name");
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#register').on('submit', function(){
  var submit = true;

  if ($('#country').val()==='-1'){
    $('#country').next(".error").html("Please fill your country");
    submit = false;
  }else
    $('#country').next(".error").html("");

  if ($('#name').val()===""){
    $('#name').next(".error").html("Please fill your name");
    submit = false;
  }else
    $('#name').next(".error").html("");


  if ($('#email').val()===""){
    $('#email').next(".error").html("Please fill your email");
    submit = false;
  }else
    $('#email').next(".error").html("");

  if ($('#password').val()===""){
    $('#password').next(".error").html("Please fill your password");
    submit = false;
  }else
    $('#password').next(".error").html("");

  if ($('[name="check"]:checked').length===0){
    $('[name="check"]:last').next(".error").html("Please check one at least");
    submit = false;
  }else
    $('[name="check"]').next(".error").html("");

  return submit;
})
```

```css
.error{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" name="register" id="register">
  Country 
  <select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="-1">Select country please</option> 
    <option value="usa">USA</option> 
    <option value="austriala">Austriala</option> 
    <option value="india">India</option>
  </select>
  <p class="error"></p>

  Name <input type="text" id="name">
  <p class="error"></p>

  Email <input type="text" id="email">
  <p class="error"></p>

  Password <input type="text" id="password">
  <p class="error"></p>

  Checkboxes 
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check_1">check 1
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check_2">check 2
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check_3">check 3
  <p class="error"></p>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Mr. Zakaria Acharki. Can please tell we are using next in code

Comment: Hi, `next()` used to get the next `p.error` after every input, so `$('#name').next(".error")` will filter just the error paragraph that come directly after the `#name` input so when we will use `.text()` to append text we will not affect other inputs errors.

Comment: The code you have written it is not working for checkbox and radio input type. Will you check it.

Comment: Hi, sure it will not work since it have a different logic, check my update for the checkboxes... for the radios what you want to check ? since one radio input at least should be selected by default..

Comment: Ok. Thank you for you time with me. But I have tried this way if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) 
     {                                    
     } 
     else 
     {                     
      $('input:checkbox').next(".error").html("Please submit your terms and conditions");
    submit = false;         
     }, will you write some code on how to select option to select validation before form submit.

Comment: Ur welcome, not sure what you mean by _how to select option to select validation before form submit_, try to update the OP with description..

Comment: Ackarki. Thank you for helping me. My question  If user does not select any value  <select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
  <option value="austriala">Austriala</option>
  <option value="india">India</option>
</select>. I want to display error like please select your country before form submited. One more question you checkbox:last. does it manitory

Comment: Hi, check the select example added to the answer.. `checkbox:last` is mandatory if you have several checkboxes if you have just one it's not.

Comment: thank so much sit ,this is very useful but I need the same jquery code in to javascript code, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. How about a native way? :)

```
function select( cssSelector ){ return document.querySleectorAll( cssSelector ) };

var inputs = select( '#register input' );  // selects array of all child inputs

//setup all validations within an object
var validations = {
   name: function( nameText ){
      //shorthand if-statements, expand if you need to
      return ( nameText === "" ) ? "error, cannot be empty" : "ok";
   },
   password: function( passText ){
      return ( passText.length < 8 )? "too short" : "ok";
   }
};

//iterate over all inputs
for( var elem in inputs ){
   if( validations[ inputs[ elem ].id ] ){ // if validation rule exists..
      console.log( "input nr " + elem + "tested\n" +
      "id = " + inputs[ elem ].id + "\n" + 
      "outcome: " + validations[ inputs[ elem ] ] );
   }
}
```

I have not tested this so there might be typos