# validate in jquery for multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one datepicker and 1 textbox and save button now I want when anyone proceed without selecting these values I want to show message fill. Means validating in jquery how I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#ser').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
                else {
                    $('#ser', 'tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }
                var row = $(this);
                var ID = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
                $('[ID*=compl]').on('click', function () {
                    $("#dialog1").dialog();
                    $('[ID*=save]').on('click', function () {                      
                        var VID = '<%=Session["value"]%>';
                        var date = $("#last_perf").val();
                        var meter = $("#txt_m").val();
                        var TypeID = '2';
                        var comp = {};
                        comp.date = date;
                        comp.meter = meter;
                        comp.VID = VID;
                        comp.ID = ID;
                        comp.TypeID=TypeID;  
                        compl_serv(comp);

                    });
                });
            });
        });

        function compl_serv(comp) {

            debugger;
            var c = {};
            c.date = comp.date;
            c.meter = comp.meter;
            c.VID = comp.VID;
            c.ID = comp.ID;
            c.TypeID = comp.TypeID;

            debugger;
            $.ajax({     
               type: "POST",
               url:"a.aspx/CSe",
               contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               data:JSON.stringify(c),
               async: true,
               cache: false,
               success: function (result) {

                    var co = JSON.parse(result.d).response;               

                             if (result.length !== "")
                        {
            $("#last_perf" + comp.date).html(comp.date);
                            $("#txt_m" + comp.meter).html(comp.meter);


                            $("#<%=save_complete_label.ClientID%>").text("successfully");
                        }

                        else
                        {                               
                            $("#<%=save_complete_label.ClientID%>").text("Fill all fields");                             
                        }

                 },

    </script>
```

HTML

```
        <div id="dialog1" class="ui-dialog"  style="display:none"  title="Basic dialog">

            <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td>  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label">Date</asp:Label> </td>
            <td>  <input id="last_perf"  class="f" value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" /><br /><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label">meter</asp:Label></td>
            <td> <input id="txt_m"   type="text"  runat="server" clientidmode="static" /><br /><br /></td> 
        <tr>
            <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  id="save">Save completed services</button><br /><br /></td>
            <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="save_complete_label" CssClass="label label-success"  runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

            </div>
```

I try through if else but this is not working.

Any solutions?

Comment: Put all input type in `form` and use `$("form").valid();` to validate all fields

Comment: Could you please provide relevant `html` and if possible a `fiddle` or `snippet` would be good..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script#answer-15072147

Comment: @GuruprasadRao CHECK UPDATE

Comment: So this is the only row that exists in table or there can be multiple rows similarly as above? Please include screenshots of your `dialog` if possible..

Comment: only 2.. one is last_perf and other is txt_m.. @GuruprasadRao

Comment: So on both the rows, if you check the `checkbox`, then relevant fields have to be filled with respect to that particular row? right?

Comment: check box? i want when any user not fill these textbox and click on button  then want to show error message " please fill' .. and when user fill and click on button then want to show message success @GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can use validate.js, it is supportable in jquery**

http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/
https://validatejs.org/

Put your HTML code in a form. if already in form use below code for example:
you can write rules also:

**js code Example: http://jsfiddle.net/beshur/D8tWs/**

```
var validator = new FormValidator('example_form', [{
name: 'req',
display: 'required',
rules: 'required'
}, 
{
name: 'alphanumeric',
rules: 'alpha_numeric'
}, {
name: 'password',
rules: 'required'
}, {
name: 'password_confirm',
display: 'password confirmation',
rules: 'required|matches[password]'
}, {
name: 'email',
rules: 'valid_email',
depends: function() {
    return Math.random() > .5;
}
}, {
name: 'minlength',
display: 'min length',
rules: 'min_length[8]'
}], function(errors, event) {
if (errors.length > 0) {
    // Show the errors
}
});
}
```