# How to show pop up only if form is submitted and validated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have written jQuery like below

```
          $("#form-search").submit(function(e){
                       e.preventDefault();
                           if (validateForm() === true) {   
                              $('#studentmodal').modal('show');
                              //alert('the form is valid');
                            }
                     return false;
           });
```

Now I want to display pop up only if form has been validated successfully. The above code is not working!!!

Please help !!!

Comment: what js error you getting ?

Comment: validate form is not defined

Comment: validateForm is not defined

Answer (score 1):

your `validateform() function` is not defined means 
that function not exist.
are you using library for validation if not then you will have to define 
validation function.
follow these two links for validate function.

[A simple jQuery form validation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script)

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can call the valid() method of jquery validation. Like

$('#form').submit(function(evt) {

```
evt.preventDefault();

.....

if( $('#form').valid() ) {
   //submit the form via ajax
} else {
   //show errors
}
```

});

});

Comment: you need to use this script and use https://
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0
/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>