# How can get my ajax method to properly valid textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", mouseOver1);
 
functionmouseOver1(){
  document.getElementById("button1").style.color="red";
}

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click",mouseOver);
functionmouseOver(){
  document.getElementById("button2").style.color="purple";
}

$("#button1").hover(function(){
  $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});

$("#button2").hover(function(){
  $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      data:{username:textbox1.val(),password:textbox2.val()
      },
      errors:function(){
        existing1-username-input-textbox:{
          required:"Youmustenteravalidexistinguseraccount.",
          minlength:"Yourusernamemustbeatleast10characterslong."
        },
        existing2-password-input-textbox:{
          required:"Youmustenteravalidpasswordassociatedwithanaccount.",
          minlength:"Yourusernamemustbeatleast10characterslong."
        }
      },
      success:function(){
        //usetheseanimatemethodsbelowifusernameandpasswordarecorrect:
        //$('#para1').animate({'left':'-105'});
        //$('.username-label').animate({'left':'-105%'});
        //$('.existing1-username-input-textbox').animate({'left':'-105%'});
        //$('.password-label').animate({'left':'-105%'});
        //$('.existing2-password-input-textbox').animate({'left':'-105%'});
        //$('#button1').animate({'left':'-105%'});
      }

    });
  });
```

```css
introh1{
  font-family:'Cambria';
  font-size:16pt;
  font:bold;
  text-align:left;
}

.introp{
  font-family:'Calibri';
  font:italic;
  font-size:12pt;
  padding:0px690px0px20px;
  text-align:left;
}

.content{
  border:2pxsolid;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}

#para1{
  padding:0px1050px0px20px;
}

#para2{
  padding:0px1099px0px20px;
}

.username-label,
.password-label{
  margin:10px0px0px300px;
  position:relative;
  top:-70px;
}

.existing1-username-input-textbox,
.existing2-password-input-textbox{
  top:-70px;
  position:relative;
}

#button1{
background-color:#add8e6;
  margin-left:390px;
  position:relative;
  top:-50px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:0px20px0px20px;
}

#button2{
background-color:#add8e6;
  margin-left:-200px;
  position:relative;
  top:-30px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:0px20px0px20px;
}

.Username-label1,
.Password-label2,
.Email-label3,
.Repeat-Email-label4{
  margin:0px0px0px300px;
  position:relative;
  top:-70px;
}
.username-new-input-textbox,
.password-new-input-textbox,
.email-new-input-textbox,
.reenter-new-input-textbox{
  position:relative;
  top:-70px;
  margin-left:20px;
}

span{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
        <h1>WelcometoCuyahogaCommunityCollegeStudentServicesOnline</h1>
      <p>CuyahogaCommunityCollegerecognizesstudents'rightstoaccesspersonalandacademicrecordsinaccordancewiththeFamilyEducationalRightsandPrivacyActof1974(FERPA)asamendedbyPublicLaw93-568.</p>
      </div>
      <br/>

      <divclass="content">
        <divclass="rowtop">
        <pid="para1">Alreadyhaveanaccountwithus?Returningusersmayloginbyenteringtheirsiteusernameandpassword.</p>
        <divclass="login">
          <labelclass="username-label"for="username-part1">Username</label>
          <inputclass="existing1-username-input-textbox"type="text"value="">
          <spanid="username_error1">*</span><br>
          <br>
          <labelclass="password-label"for="password-part2">Password</label>
          <inputclass="existing2-password-input-textbox"type="password"value="">
          <spanid="password_error2">*</span><br>
          <buttonid="button1">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <divclass="rowbottom">
        <pid="para2">Newusers,pleasecreateanewaccountbyprovidinguswithsomebasicinformation.</p>
        <divclass="new_customers_info">
          <labelclass="Username-label1"for="new-user-name-part-1">Username</label>
          <inputclass="username-new-input-textbox"type="text"value=""><br/>
          <br/>
          <labelclass="Password-label2"for="password-new-part2">Password</label>
        <inputclass="password-new-input-textbox"type="password"value=""><br/>
        <br/>
        <labelclass="Email-label3"for="email-new">EmailAddress</label>
        <inputclass="email-new-input-textbox"type="email"value=""><br/>
        <br/>
        <labelclass="Repeat-Email-label4"for="repeat-new-email">RepeatEmailAddress</label>
        <inputclass="reenter-new-input-textbox"type="email"value="">

        <buttonid="button2">CreateAccount</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <footer>CuyahogaCommunityCollege</footer>
  <footer>700CarnegieAvenue,Cleveland,Ohio,44115</footer>
</div>
<scriptsrc="Home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello Everyone,

I am trying get this ajax method to work in order to validate input textfields for the upper boxes, but how can I get it to working?
What I am doing wrong?

I want it to work such that if a user inputs the wrong username and password, it display error messages and it won't animate the old content out to the left side.
How can I fix my ajax method?

Comment: The snippet above is already giving a hint «Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :»

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette How can I fix this?

Comment: Well... I just indented your code correctly to make it readable... `$(document).ready(function(){` isn't closed.

Comment: Within the ajax function... the `error` handler is intended to handle ajax communication error... not form validation errors. You have to validate the inputs BEFORE sending values via ajax. And (lol) there is no `url`!! Do you know what Ajax is ?

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette Are you telling me I can't use the ajax method then? I want to still use Ajax. Can I use ajax internally then?

Comment: Ajax in intended to get external content. Not to validate user input. Ajax needs a `url` to got transport some data and come back with a result.

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette  Yes, Ajax loads data from the server without refreshing the page. How can I get my ajax method to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143589/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-user445555).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to nail this question down...

After the [nice chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143589/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-user445555) we had, you understood that Ajax is NOT usefull to do what you expect actually. And you undertood what it is usefull to.

So you don't have to use Ajax **at all** to validate one or more textboxes.
Instead, use [jQuery Validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) (or some other plugin... There is plenty! Google "JavaScript validation")

A **great SO answer** I suggest you to look at is [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15072147/2159528), where plenty users agreed on the fact that it is *«much better than their actual documentation»*.

I think this plugin is the most used of all... At least the most known.

I also suggest you to read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression, which is a way to find strings parts efficiently... And it can be used with the validation plugin above.

To conclude, this [super usefull tool](https://regex101.com/#javascript) to test a regular expression is a must.

---

**--EDIT--**
Next step is: [using Ajax in the `submitHandler`][5]