# Jquery validation: accept only number and punctuation marks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use jQuery validation to validate a field that only accepts number and punctuation marks, but there doesn't seem to be a defined rule for it. I've searched google but I've found nothing useful.

Any ideas?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can use [`jQuery.isNumeric()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15060355/9192223

Comment: use html [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) and avoid javascript.

Comment: You can use: https://jqueryvalidation.org/number-method/ Demo is also given. You can test it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rules object you can do the following:

```
rules: {
    yourField:{
        regex: /^[0-9!?.;,]+$/
    }
}
```

You can add the punctuation marks you want to that regex.

Comment: I use this cannot type number but letters can, what I expected is only can type a number and punctuation marks sorry I am so bad with regex

Comment: edited the code only number and punctuation marks are allow `/[^0-9!?.;,=<>-+:]+$/`