# Laravel, how to show forms error with ajax submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datepicker

I use ajax to submit a form without having to reload the page after, but I really don't know how to get the forms errors, especially for the required fields.

Here is my form, it's a simple form with two `datepicker`:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="date_debut" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Date de début</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" id="date_debut" name="date_debut" class="datepicker-here form-control" data-timepicker="true" data-language='fr' placeholder="Choisir une date" />
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="date_fin" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Date de fin</label>

     <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="date_fin" name="date_fin" class="datepicker-here form-control" data-timepicker="true" data-language='fr' placeholder="Choisir une date" />
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
        <button id="ajoutDispoButton" onclick="myfunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            Ajouter
        </button>
      </div>
     </div>

     <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" class="form-control" value="{{$user->id}}" required>
</form>
```

And here is my Ajax call :

```
 function myfunction(param){
        var date_debut = $('#date_debut').val();
        console.log(date_debut);
        var date_fin = $('#date_fin').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('createDispo') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                user_id: user_id,
                date_debut: date_debut,
                date_fin: date_fin,
            },

            success: function (data) {
                $("#centralModalSuccess").modal();
                $("#date_fin").val("");
                $("#date_debut").val("");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                console.log(errors);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here my controller :

```
public function createDispo(Request $request){
    $user = User::find($request->user_id);
    $disponibilite = new Disponibilite();
    $disponibilite->date_debut = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$request->date_debut);
    $disponibilite->date_fin =  Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$request->date_fin);
    $user->disponibilites()->save($disponibilite);

    return response()->json(['ok' => 'ok']); // Return OK to user's browser
}
```

I think this is not the right way to proceed, but this work. The problem is that I want to handle the validations errors, my fields are required but I can send the ajax call even if they are empty.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: do you want to block sending the ajax call? Or display the errors after the call returns?

Comment: I don't know if there is a best solution, if the both do the same thing I want the most simple ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation

Answer (score 0):

you can make form validation with jquery instead of laravel validation

Look at this question : [A simple jQuery form validation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script)

Answer (score 0):

Add validation in controller function

```
public function createDispo(Request $request){
   $request->validate([
    'date_debut' => 'required',
    'date_fin' => 'required',
]);
// your code 
}
```

and display the errors in html.