# Javascript - Laravel (blade)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

Im starting a laravel mini project at the moment and I want to make a field which gets filled by two other fields in the form, Im not so good with the javascript so I copied one that worked on normal html+php page but it doesnt work on blade, Im extending a layout file called app.blade.php, the script I am using is already added in the screenshot of the layouts file.

So any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEsDi.png)

[Layout that I am extending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvY8q.png)

Comment: Never rely on client-side validation -- that should be secondary. Start with [Laravel's built-in validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) libraries and perform validation in your controller.

Comment: However, since you're using jQuery, you can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15072147/2535504) for later client-side validation. I've never used the validate plugin before but it looks fairly simple. Also check out the [native HTML required attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).