# How do I make a form redirect you after submitting the form with required inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML JS form for a contact form on my website, but I want it to redirect to a thank your page after the submit button is clicked. I can do that on it's own, but it happens every time I click the button, but I only want it to happen when the required areas are filled in.

I have tried an action tag on the form btw, it doesn't work for some reason.

Code (full screen it too see the button) :

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function () {
  location.href = "/contactty.html";
};
```

```css
    .cntct-bg {
        background-color: #4158D0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%);
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .contact-cont {
        position: absolute;
        top: 6%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form {
        background: #ffffff;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 2vw 4vw;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 600px;
        border-radius: 10px;

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form h1 {
        color: #555555;
        font-weight: 800;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-family: var(--black);

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form input,
    form textarea {
        border: 0;
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 20px;
        outline: none;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: var(--medium);

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form textarea {
        min-width: 93.33%;
        max-width: 93.33%;
        min-height: 80px;

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form button {
        padding: 15px;
        background: #ff5361;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 18px;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        border-radius: 30px;
    
        z-index: 1;
    
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 0px #a83740;
    }
    
    .form button:active {
        box-shadow: none;
        transform:  translateY(8px);
    }
```

```html
<body class="cntct-bg">
  <div class="contact-cont">
    <form action="/contactty.html" id="contact-form">
      <h1>Get in touch</h1>
      <input type="hidden" name="contact_number">
      <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Whats on your mind?" required></textarea>
      <div class="tscheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tsy" name="tsy" value="agreed" required>
        <label for="tsy">Accept the <span><a href="/tos.html">terms of service</var></a></span></label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="submit()">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `checkAllInput()` is validatind data.
- I have selected all `inputs` and then looping through them and validating   `if (input.value == null || input.value == "")` weather it's empty or not.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
  if (checkAllInput()) {
    location.href = "/contactty.html";
  }
};

function checkAllInput() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  inpputs.forEach(input => {
    if (input.value == null || input.value == "") {
      alert("please enter all data");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.cntct-bg {
  background-color: #4158D0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%);
  overflow: scroll;
}

.contact-cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

form {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2vw 4vw;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

form h1 {
  color: #555555;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: var(--black);
  z-index: 1;
}

form input,
form textarea {
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: var(--medium);
  z-index: 1;
}

form textarea {
  min-width: 93.33%;
  max-width: 93.33%;
  min-height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}

form button {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ff5361;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 0px #a83740;
}

.form button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(8px);
}
```

```html
<body class="cntct-bg">
  <div class="contact-cont">
    <form action="/contactty.html" id="contact-form">
      <h1>Get in touch</h1>
      <input type="hidden" name="contact_number">
      <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Whats on your mind?" required></textarea>
      <div class="tscheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tsy" name="tsy" value="agreed" required>
        <label for="tsy">Accept the <span><a href="/tos.html">terms of service</var></a></span></label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="submit()">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This works, but doesnt redirect if all data is in the form

Comment: could you please explain me what do you mean by doesn't redirect if all data is in form?

Comment: I guess it was css problem you was not able to enter name in my solution, Now I havechange css you can try it gain

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's work for you

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function () {
var count = 0;
var len = document.querySelectorAll('[required]').forEach(current=> {
  if(current.value == ''){ count = count + 1;}
});
if(count == 0){
  window.location.href = "/contactty.html";
}
  };
```

```css
    .cntct-bg {
        background-color: #4158D0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%);
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .contact-cont {
        position: absolute;
        top: 6%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form {
        background: #ffffff;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 2vw 4vw;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 600px;
        border-radius: 10px;

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form h1 {
        color: #555555;
        font-weight: 800;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-family: var(--black);

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form input,
    form textarea {
        border: 0;
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 20px;
        outline: none;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: var(--medium);

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form textarea {
        min-width: 93.33%;
        max-width: 93.33%;
        min-height: 80px;

        z-index: 1;
    }

    form button {
        padding: 15px;
        background: #ff5361;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 18px;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        border-radius: 30px;
    
        z-index: 1;
    
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 0px #a83740;
    }
    
    .form button:active {
        box-shadow: none;
        transform:  translateY(8px);
    }
```

```html
<body class="cntct-bg">
  <div class="contact-cont">
    <form action="/contactty.html" id="contact-form">
      <h1>Get in touch</h1>
      <input type="hidden" name="contact_number">
      <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Whats on your mind?" required></textarea>
      <div class="tscheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tsy" name="tsy" value="agreed" required>
        <label for="tsy">Accept the <span><a href="/tos.html">terms of service</var></a></span></label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="submit()">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope using java script function will help you out. For the all kinds of validation we can use JQuery to make it smoother and faster(please find out more from the link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script#:~:text=you%20can%20use%20jquery%20validator,form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060292/a-simple-jquery-form-validation-script#:%7E:text=you%20can%20use%20jquery%20validator,form).  )

Hope this will help you :-).

```js
function validateForm() {
  let x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="action_to_be_taken" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```